# Advice on where/how to run client app on server?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, c#-4.0

I have been writing an app that runs on a server in London (interacts with other in house applications) and then writes results to a mysql db. App then displays results in a webpage (gridviews linked to the db). Currently this is a webapp using asp.net and c#. This is run multiple times in the morning and needs to be run as and when required by client (not on a scehdule)

Although current asp works well, I would like to move this to a desktop application (wpf/c#4).

Requirements are that the bulk of the code (all the interaction with other apps and writing results to db happen on Server). It's a global app and clients in Asia unable to run locally.

Whats the best way to do this? I presume it's possible to write all the server code that writes results to the db to an exe then the client (wpf app) call the server exe when the app is to rewrite results to db then simply link into the db?

As you can probably tell, I am quite new to this! Looked at Silverlight but all code is run on client correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think the typical solution for this is a server / client model.  The server (in London) exposes a (WCF) service that your clients (WPF apps, if you want) call.

Comment: ok thanks for that, was just reading the same. So this is basically creating a web service which client then calls?

Comment: Exacltly, just upgrade the website and add some asmx files, and subscribe to it in your application. You'll be just calling those methods from your app. You you can create a WCF app. The result is the same.

Comment: cool thanks, shall continue the googling for further info but that points me in the right direction!